# In Android Google Map run in 5.1 But Not run 4.2 Android

Tags: android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/com.example.admin.map-2.apk
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4820)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4430)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4372)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/com.example.admin.map-2.apk
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4805)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4430) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4372) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: enable multidex

Comment: It because you didn't setup multidex preoperly ...

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use only map service then only compile dependency of map:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
```

do not compile the complete play service dependency:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

It will solve your problem.